# Is it possible to move from Apache to HAProxy/nginx as reverse proxy?

Tags: apache, nginx, haproxy

We are using Apache as reverse proxy (`mod_proxy`). The most important feature for us is url mapping (simple url rewriting) including rewriting of cookie paths. As I surprisingly learned nginx does not rewrite cookie paths (with factory modules). I am not sure but I believe HAProxy can do this. Apache is too heavy only for this job. So can you comment on what to use in this situation? (backend is a Java app server e.g. Tomcat)

1. Continue using Apache
2. Use nginx with some 3rd party modules (lua etc.)
3. Use HAProxy

Answer (score 0):

I would investigate HAProxy, unless you are wanting to cache that content as well (server offload). It has pretty impressive cookie support.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, I have found HAProxy very lightweight and easy to work with.  You can define URL/cookie rewrites with the [reqrep/reqirep](http://code.google.com/p/haproxy-docs/wiki/reqrep) keyword, which can be applied to anything in an HTTP header request.  For example:

```
# add cookie 'backend=2' for any HTTP method followed by
#  '/img' only or '/img/' followed by anything:

reqirep ^[^:\ ]*\ /img[/\ ].* \0\nCookie:\ backend=2
```

Same idea for URL rewrites:

```
# replace "/static/" with "/" at the beginning of any request path:

reqrep ^([^\ ]*)\ /static/(.*)     \1\ /\2
```